# Laravel Install with Composer is Creating Two composer.json Files

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am just getting started both with Composer and Laravel.

I used Composer to include the Laravel installer:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/installer": "v1.3.5"
}
```

When I ran the Laravel installer, it created a subdirectory with the name specified in the command: `laravel new name`. My project now has a `composer.json` file in both the root folder and the Laravel installation sub-folder.

Is this what's supposed to happen? It seems to me that I should only have one `composer.json` per project.

Comment: Actually you have installed it in different way. That's why this situation created. In Laravel folder there should be composer.json which for that project.

Comment: The Laravel installer does not belong in your project and is not part of it. It's just a global helper function to scaffold a new laravel application, so you should only install it globally (`composer global require laravel/installer`) so you have the `laravel` function available. And yes, every new composer project then has its own composer.json file. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation for more details and different options how to create a Laravel project.

Comment: @Sonny can you please upvote the answer if it helped you and for helping others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a Laravel project using composer as describes below:: *(on windows)*

1. First go to file directory where you want to create the Laravel project say "`C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_5_4`"
2. Press `Alt+d` then you will see directy URL will be highlighted, then type "`cmd`" and press `Enter` and command promt should appear.
3. Then just copy these code "`composer create-project laravel/laravel ./ "5.4.*" --prefer-dist`" and press Enter.

Sit back and relax, you are done.
Note: *You can change the version as you want.*